# error converting a string to double

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert a string to double in Visual Basic, but I keep getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "48.00 " to type
>   'Double' is not valid.'

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ratingupdater_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ratingupdater.Tick
        If hum = "" Then
            Return
        End If
        If temp = "" Then
            Return
        End If
        If hum = "NAN" Then
            Return
        End If
        If temp = "NAN" Then
            Return
        End If
        'humidity Rating
        Dim tempolary As Double
        tempolary = CDbl(hum)
        tempval.Text = tempolary
        If tempolary > 75 Then
            humrating.Text = "High"
            humrating.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If tempolary >= 65 And tempolary < 75 Then
            humrating.Text = "Mid"
            humrating.ForeColor = Color.Orange
        End If
        If tempolary < 65 Then
            humrating.Text = "Low"
            humrating.ForeColor = Color.Green
        End If
        tempolary = 0
    End Sub
```

(`hum` is a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Double.Parse(hum) in your code

Comment: I just tried it and now I'm getting this error: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'.

Comment: What is the actual value of hum u are passing

Comment: hum is "48.0 " I'm reading it from a Arduino serial connection.

Comment: Hum contain spaces I guess trim the spaces before passing it to function

Comment: I fixed the error using Double.Parse(hum).Replace(".", ","). Thanks